# Share buttons share homepage instead of actual page

Tags: share, sharethis, social-media

For a client's blog I added social share buttons at the bottom each blogpage:
http://www.pano-solutions.be/5-tips-voor-een-great-place-to-work.php

I use the sharethis plugin for this. However, when I click on any of the sharebuttons, It will share the mainpage of the website instead of the blogpage. Not very usefull. I searched the FAQ on sharethis, but didn't find any usefull help there.

Someone knows how I can fix this or know any working alternatives or good practises on how to do this myself?

Answer (score 1):

ShareThis has a tweak where you can add: `expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'` to each button, forcing the share buttons to share the link in the post instead of the link in the broswer.

The code would look something similar to this:

```
    < span class='st_twitter_hcount' expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'/>
< span class='st_facebook_hcount' expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'/> 
< span class='st_googleplus_hcount' expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'/> 
< span class='st_linkedin_hcount' expr:st_title='data:post.title' expr:st_url='data:post.url'/>
```

Comment: I had many share buttons ( Custom share button from Sharethis ) in one page and the above solution didn't work for me, but adding the `data-short-url` solved the issue.